# How to write data onto csv file over a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, text, rows

I want to write data onto several rows in a csv file. With this code I am only getting a single line written onto file. Need help.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    with open("output.csv",'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow([value1, value2, value3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering the error because it is re-writing a csv for every iteration in your loop. You should move the with open() statement outside of your loop block.

Comment: And the creation of the `csv.writer` should be outside the loop for that matter (it would probably work without that change, but rebuilding the `writer` over and over is slow/wasteful).

Comment: Is there a way I can append the data without overwriting it?

Comment: yes. There is a post by Alvaro here that shows the code

Comment: I changed it to "with open("output.csv",'a') as f:" and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try opening the file only once and then doing the loop:

```
with open("output.csv",'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    for item in list_A:
        writer.writerow([value1, value2, value3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `w` option in `open` as follows:

```
import csv
list_A = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
with open("output.csv",'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in list_A:
        writer.writerow([1,0,0,0])
```